# Is there a MapCache 1.2.1 (currently last) binary for Windows?

Tags: mapserver, windows, mapcache

I use MapServer 6.4.1 installed with OSGeo4W.

I cannot find equivalent MapCache (1.2.1) binary for Windows and I do not know how to compile it. It is supposed to be part of the mapserver suite.

Can anyone point me to a distribution?

Comment: See http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94597/how-to-install-and-use-mapcache

Comment: hi @user30184, thanks. i know that Q because i wrote it.. :-). this question is a followup question.. as i wrote, i dont know how to compile it and i was wondering if someone did it already. thanks

Comment: Ok, I await the answer too. I have only been able to test MapCache on Windows with that ancient MS4W development version.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried http://www.maptools.org/ms4w/index.phtml?page=README_INSTALL_dev.html#g-mapcache-apache-module?

The ms4w package might have more mapserver packages than OSGEO4W.

Comment: hi, thanks! ms4w is quite old (2012) and has mapserver 6.0.3 and no mapcache. the dev build has mapserver 6.1 and mapcache (didnt mention a version but probably 1). the current more stable version of mapcache was released in 2014 so it is not there.. :-(

Comment: You could ask Tamas Szekeres if he can include it in his gisinternals build. Unfortunately, his site is down at the moment :-(

Comment: thanks @Andre Joost. didnt know that site but now ill test it from time to time.

Answer (score 0):

In this ticket there is comments about mapcache been built too:
http://trac.osgeo.org/mapserver/ticket/4106

I could not found mapcache binaries at mapserver distributed here: [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).

Comment: hi, thanks for the link! i search it and even though its title is 'mapcache windows build' i cannot find there or in their site a compiled version :\

Answer (score 0):

Last version of ms4w which I could find http://dl.maptools.org/dl/ms4w/ms4w_3.1.0-beta1.zip